# Rails turbolinks server with react-native-webview app and firebase messaging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firebase, react-native, devise, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have the following setup:

A rails server, which has a basic user login using the [devise](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise) gem.
There I've defined a `User` and a `Device` model where each user may have multiple devices via a `has_many` relationship on the user. The `Device` model has a single attribute- a token which I would use to send push notifications to using the [rpush](https://github.com/rpush/rpush) gem.

A react-native app using the [react-native-webview](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview#readme) package and the [react-native-firebase/messaging](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/tree/master#readme) package. The thing is, that I don't really know how to send the firebase device token to the server correctly.

What I've got so far is that I've overridden the rails devise `registrations#new` view to the following:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :devices, @user do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.hidden_field :token, {value: nil} %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Here you can see that I've added a hidden field for the token, which I insert in the react-native app once I've landed on the `/users/sign_up` page using the following code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

const MyWebView = () => {
  const [uri] = useState("http:\/\/10.0.2.2:3000");
  const [webViewRef, setWebViewRef] = useState(null);

  const postMessageThatTurbolinksLoadOccured = `
    document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
      window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage("turbolinks:load");
    })`;

  function onMessage(obj) {
    const event = obj.nativeEvent;

    if(event.data != "turbolinks:load") return;

    if(event.url==`${uri}/users/sign_in` || event.url==`${uri}/users/sign_up`) {
      messaging().getToken().then(token => {
        const insertTokenCode = `
          document.getElementById("user_devices_attributes_0_token").value = "${token}";
        `;
        webViewRef.injectJavaScript(insertTokenCode);
      })
    }
  }

  // This is here only temporarily
  messaging().onMessage(remoteMessage => {
    Alert.alert(remoteMessage.notification.body);
  })

  return (
    <WebView
      ref={setWebViewRef}
      source={{ uri: `${uri}/users/sign_in` }}
      injectedJavaScript={postMessageThatTurbolinksLoadOccured}
      onMessage={onMessage}
    />
    );
};

export default MyWebView;
```

And this actually works fine, but once I got around to testing the rails app and I tried setting the hidden field value in the specs I got an error:

```
     Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotInteractableError:
       element not interactable
```

Which made me think that this approach is "hacky". So does anybody know a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone who encounters this problem as well,I figured it out a while ago, but haven't gotten around to answering the question.

I started using firebase channels instead of having to register each device on the server and just send the message to the channel instead, which removes the need for me to save each device ID on the server. Like so:

- For the react-native app

```
import { Alert } from "react-native";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

const MyView = () => {
  const messagingInstance = messaging()
  messagingInstance.subscribeToTopic("welcome").then(() => {
    messagingInstance.onMessage(message => {
      if(message.from == "/topics/welcome") {
        Alert.alert(message.notification.body);
        messagingInstance.unsubscribeFromTopic("welcome");
      }
    });
  });

  return (
    <WebView
      source={{ uri: `http:\/\/10.0.2.2:3000` }}
    />
    );
};
export default MyView;
```

- on the server I have a job which sends a notification via the channel using the [fcm](https://github.com/decision-labs/fcm) gem

```
class SendGreetingPushNotificationJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(*args)
    fcm = FCM.new(Rails.application.config.FIREBASE_SERVER_KEY)
    fcm.send_to_topic("welcome", notification: {body: "Welcome to MyApp!"})
  end
end
```